# How to exclude all uart debug traces ( security, code size, release of application )?

Tags: contiki-ng

I'm looking for official way in Contiki-NG for exclude all debug traces from code (security, code size, release version of application).

I have used  extra definition in my Makefile
-DLOG_CONF_OUTPUT="(void)(0);" -Wno-unused-value
and code size is reduced but I should add -Wno-unused-value for avoid multiple warnings.

What can be better way to replace LOG_CONF_OUTPUT with something else ?

Regards,
Eugene

Comment: have you tried /dev/null?

Comment: I need to exclude those from source code, not from terminal

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify your actual goal.

Comment: I would like to exclude uart traces for secure reason and reduce code size ( release version of application). UART is not initialized also,  -DUART0_ENABLED=0 is defined.

Comment: Hit the edit button under your question, and edit the question to include what you exactly want.